# How can we get First flash file data in asp.net (C#) after two or three form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, shopping-cart

- Our team working on flash/Asp.net shopping cart projects
- In our projects we need to get previous flash file data.
- After two or three form submission the first page flash file data are missing.
- How can we maintain the state of flash file data?
- If any idea please help our team to do the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET allows you to save values using session state, a storage mechanism that is accessible from all pages requested by a single Web browser session. Therefore, you can use session state to store user-specific information. Session state is similar to application state, except that it is scoped to the current browser session. If different users are using your application, each user session has a different session state. In addition, if a user leaves your application and then returns later after the session timeout period, session state information is lost and a new session is created for the user. Session state is stored in the Session key/value dictionary.

//Storing UserName in Session

Session["UserName"] = txtUser.Text;

//Check weather session variable null or not

```
    if (Session["UserName"] != null)

    {

        //Retrieving UserName from Session

        lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome : " + Session["UserName"];

    }

    else

    {

     //Do Something else

    }
```

For more information
[Exploring Session in ASP.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExploringSession.aspx)